# Adding custom field in rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field, helper

I'm working in a rails app and for country state and city select field I want to create a custom field so that It can be used later as already existed field.

**For example**

```
f.country_select :country
```

Above field should automatically generate a select with countries list.

I want three fields country, state and city so connected that when country field selected state select field gets state list and when state is selected city select works same.

Thank you for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should start from [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) . In this rails cast you can understand how to dynamically populate data in child(`State`) select box on basis of parent(`Country`) selection.
You need to extend functionality for cities same.

But in given tutorial you should have countries and state data. For managing that data you can use [City-State](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state).

In tutorial it is used like `Country.find(:all)`, So you need to change it to `CS.get`. and for state of a selected country like `CS.get :us`.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add this method to `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` class
here is example for

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def error_message_on(method, options = {})
    @template.error_message_on(@object_name, method, objectify_options(options))
  end
end
```

and then you can do this

```
= f.label :description, I18n.t(:description)
= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control'
= f.error_message_on :description
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem `city-state` [github gem link](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state) .